# Opengl on PictureBox toolbox in Visual Studio 2008.net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, opengl

How can I use Opengl in PictureBox toolbox in Visual C++.I didn't come across any document on internet.Do you know any document,tutorial,code example etc. about this topic?

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I think yo can render to any window context.
Simple get the HWND and use it for context creation.

```
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hWnd, HDC * hDC, HGLRC * hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    int iFormat;

    // get the device context (DC)
    *hDC = GetDC( hWnd );

    // set the pixel format for the DC
    ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );
    pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |
                  PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat( *hDC, &pfd );
    SetPixelFormat( *hDC, iFormat, &pfd );

    // create and enable the render context (RC)
    *hRC = wglCreateContext( *hDC );
    wglMakeCurrent( *hDC, *hRC );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've manage to put it in pictureBox, using [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/OpenGLViewWinForms.aspx) with [modification](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3573453/wglCreateContext-always-return-null-the-solution-i.aspx), you'll have only to change the COpenGL Constructor to PictureBox (previously Form). But, only the last picturebox is rendered anyway. Still working on it...